# How to set image on touch of canvas html5

Tags: jquery, css, html5-canvas

I am creating sketch book in html5 which will use mouse & touch to draw. Inside it, It has Pencil & Brush tool. When user select Pencil and draw from mouse then instead of mouse pointer on screen, Pencil will come & draw. Below is the css.

```
.drawing canvas.pencil.pressed{
    cursor:url("../images/drawing_game/cursors/pencil-pressed-big.png"),auto
}
@media (max-width:480px){
    .drawing canvas.pencil.pressed{
        cursor:url("../images/drawing_game/cursors/pencil-pressed.png"),auto
     }
}
```

But when I try to draw from finger touch then how to write CSS for that such that pencil icon will come ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: post js html code here

Comment: I think you need to investigate how `canvas` is getting assigned the css classes `pencil` and `pressed`. I suspect `pressed` is getting added on some `mousedown` event handler, but there is no account of `touchstart` on your code for touch interaction.

Comment: pencil is inside canvas , so you can't apply cursor to parent with css , you've to do it with js

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is by using JavaScript. Somehow touchscreens are not meant to convey hover states. Please refer to this [blog post](http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/). It provides more information on the matter and explains the JavaScript workarounds which can be used.